# How can a C++ state machine communicate with a python script?

Tags: ros, rospy, pocketsphinx, roscpp

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am wondering how I could tell a python script to execute from a c++ code.
My specific problem is, to activate a pocketsphinx script to recognize spoken commands.
But pocketsphinx is written in python...

Is the solution to make an action client / server for the communication?
I am new to ROS and a bit confused on how this transition between C++ and python works.

Regards,
Max

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12393/how-can-a-c++-state-machine-communicate-with-a-python-script?/) by [madmax](https://answers.ros.org/users/1492/madmax/) on ROS Answers with karma: 496 on 2011-12-17

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can define a [simple service in Python](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/Tutorials/WritingServiceClient%28python%29) with a [C++ client](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/Tutorials/WritingServiceClient%28c%2B%2B%29).

If you need a more elaborate structure for controlling the service, [actionlib](http://www.ros.org/wiki/actionlib) may provide a better solution.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2011-12-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [madmax](https://answers.ros.org/users/1492/madmax/) on 2011-12-17**:
I see, thank you for the explanation!

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2011-12-17**:
You can return a result message from a simple service. Actionlib provides more sophisticated features, such as cancelling or preempting an earlier request.

**Comment by [madmax](https://answers.ros.org/users/1492/madmax/) on 2011-12-17**:
So, actionlib when I want to have feedback?